# How to insert picture to google docs using the url link coming from google form response spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

[How to insert picture to google docs using the url link coming from google form response spreadsheet]

I need help, I have a google form that allow the user to upload their photo. My problem is, I have to link the google docs report to the [url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Pih6.jpg) photo under the column [11] of the response spreadsheet.

here is my code

```
var Photo = e.values[11];
      
  var templateFile = DriveApp.getFileById("link-of-docReport");
  var templateResponseFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("this-is-the-path-for-uploaded-photo");
  var copy = templateFile.makeCopy(LastName + ", " + FirstName, templateResponseFolder);
  
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());
  
  var body = doc.getBody();
  
  body.replaceText("Photo", Photo);
```

Comment: Are the usrs providing you an URL of a picture on THEIR drive or do they upload the picture as an [attachment](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9308632?hl=en), so a file is created on YOUR drive?

Answer (score 0):

### Using `replaceText` will replace a string through another string - not through an actual photo

Instead you need to

- find the placeholder as an element
- find its parent
- insert the picture into the parent
- delete the placeholder element

**Sample how to insert a file that it on your drive where the id is known:**

```js
  var blob = DriveApp.getFileById("id").getBlob();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var element = body.findText("Photo").getElement();
  element.getParent().asParagraph().insertInlineImage(1, blob);
  element.removeFromParent();
```

To extract the id from the url of a file on your drive, you nee to use regex, e.g. as done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56747203/11599789).